# HTTP "GET" Method Not Returning Any Data in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, get, asp.net-web-api2

I've already ran a "POST" method to my API, and I successfully retrieved my token, username, and other data.

Now as I run my "GET" method in Xcode, it seems as though I'm not getting any data at all. I ran my Web API through fiddler, and data is being returned, so I know it must be a problem with my code.

Here is the code for my get request (I pass in my token to receive my profile data) :

```
NSString *get = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"g0pww0uXSrffNtJWWUrguHo-Zwr85EvtbKpAk46oea1Ayl2s7mncoDcXF8f-IJcBrWdxuGFYX3Ua5Tv7ea_IT0HWDB4nyVXrJKrU5f2gpnry4f-qF8zlyaMOQloVIIcqQo0nOY9B87cxvSlAwkZR4hub7CPvXMGpHAJixov2Sb-sE8jEv--cJ1l0Cfr6f3E0nX47-GdalB1XCtIJZgX6ZqpRWxqFaiMKRSZpD5-n087nSfUwQLNAIIA4AG8Hljh1yw3gCHi8fz40ARqkFyOIoXJm6tjtbwZGM44imm4DgP1GeDRqSkM7rVHUeMNmzsmsZWcAxMXDb_P9GbvLwD4_AqsTvuZ00r5UaydPB4m-po4jDf_e3HRKkUOQHAD3jTG_I2TUd6QD3mEyKbK41JsjDDv0LaLvBfTCUskZJKOjXDRanwQJWkselAv5cc5-bEIpvw7HYuFf1lM-O0LSLAXeGYfZS7H-KOdFPJCFUAGO0RH7zdJgatO-sqdx0GNyN_E3"];

    NSData *getData = [get dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *getLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[getData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *getRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [getRequest setValue:@"Bearer g0pww0uXSrffNtJWWUrguHo-Zwr85EvtbKpAk46oea1Ayl2s7mncoDcXF8f-IJcBrWdxuGFYX3Ua5Tv7ea_IT0HWDB4nyVXrJKrU5f2gpnry4f-qF8zlyaMOQloVIIcqQo0nOY9B87cxvSlAwkZR4hub7CPvXMGpHAJixov2Sb-sE8jEv--cJ1l0Cfr6f3E0nX47-GdalB1XCtIJZgX6ZqpRWxqFaiMKRSZpD5-n087nSfUwQLNAIIA4AG8Hljh1yw3gCHi8fz40ARqkFyOIoXJm6tjtbwZGM44imm4DgP1GeDRqSkM7rVHUeMNmzsmsZWcAxMXDb_P9GbvLwD4_AqsTvuZ00r5UaydPB4m-po4jDf_e3HRKkUOQHAD3jTG_I2TUd6QD3mEyKbK41JsjDDv0LaLvBfTCUskZJKOjXDRanwQJWkselAv5cc5-bEIpvw7HYuFf1lM-O0LSLAXeGYfZS7H-KOdFPJCFUAGO0RH7zdJgatO-sqdx0GNyN_E3" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://appointmentreminder4.azurewebsites.net/Profile"]];
    [getRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [getRequest setValue:getLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:getData];

    NSURLResponse *getRequestResponse;
    NSData *getRequestHandler = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:getRequest returningResponse:&getRequestResponse error:nil];

     NSString *getRequestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[getRequestHandler bytes] length:[getRequestHandler length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"getRequestReply: %@", getRequestReply);
```

The output is this:

```
2014-12-30 11:32:23.384 ARTest[612:303] getRequestReply: 
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

All help is appreciated :)

EDIT:

getRequestHandler returns (null)

getData returns A BUNCH of populated data

Comment: Did you try printing the getRequestHandler i.e. the NSData object? Is that also empty?

Comment: Let me try that right now and I'll edit my question to add those in

Comment: Yeah, the handler doesn't return anything, but the data does

Comment: As per Apple docs: The downloaded data for the URL request returns nil if a connection could not be created or if the download fails.

Comment: Perhaps I'll have to go into Fiddler and double check to see that I'm passing in the appropriate values